# Acceder a los datos de este Json con PHP

Tags: php, json

`[{
  "GameId": 53614,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Day": "2018-09-28T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-09-28T14:10:00",
  "Status": "InProgress",
  "AwayTeamId": 16,
  "HomeTeamId": 20,
  "AwayTeamName": "CHW",
  "HomeTeamName": "MIN",
  "GlobalGameId": 10053614,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 10000016,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 10000020,
  "PregameOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 509945,
    "Sportsbook": "BetDSI",
    "GameId": 53614,
    "Created": "2018-09-28T14:12:36",
    "Updated": "2018-09-28T16:27:12",
    "HomeMoneyLine": -185,
    "AwayMoneyLine": 169,
    "HomePointSpread": -1.7,
    "AwayPointSpread": 1.7,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": 140,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -163,
    "OverUnder": 9.0,
    "OverPayout": -123,
    "UnderPayout": -123
  }],
  "LiveOdds": []
}]`

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a este json puedes decodificarlo primero como un array. Si guardas ese json en una variable llamada $json, podrias hacer:

```
$datos = json_decode($json, true);
```

luego, para acceder a los datos, tienes que tener en cuenta que tienes un array de objetos. Esto es, los datos estan en el primer indice (0). Para acceder, por ej a SeasonType, tienes que hacer:

```
$seasontype = $datos[0]["SeasonType"];
```

Comment: Deben ser corchetes en lugar de paréntesis no?

Comment: Cierto @Sr1871 fallo mío. Lo he corregido en la respuesta. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Segun la estructura, lo que tienes es un array de objetos, por lo tanto puedes hacerlo asi:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $objeto)
{
   echo $objeto['GameId'];

   foreach ($objeto['PregameOdds'] as $i => $obj) {
       echo $obj['GameOddId'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hice un pequeño código funcional donde puede guiarte, si ves dentro del código coloque un `foreach` para recorrer el **array** en dado caso si tienes mas de un indice en ese array json y la otra acceder directamente seteando el indice si siempre quieres acceder a uno solo:

[Ejemplo funcional de como obtener un valor array json](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$array%20=%20'[%7B%5Cn%22GameId%22:%2053614,%5Cn%22Season%22:%202018,%5Cn%22SeasonType%22:%201,%5Cn%22Day%22:%20%222018-09-28T00:00:00%22,%5Cn%22DateTime%22:%20%222018-09-28T14:10:00%22,%5Cn%22Status%22:%20%22InProgress%22,%5Cn%22AwayTeamId%22:%2016,%5Cn%22HomeTeamId%22:%2020,%5Cn%22AwayTeamName%22:%20%22CHW%22,%5Cn%22HomeTeamName%22:%20%22MIN%22,%5Cn%22GlobalGameId%22:%2010053614,%5Cn%22GlobalAwayTeamId%22:%2010000016,%5Cn%22GlobalHomeTeamId%22:%2010000020,%5Cn%22PregameOdds%22:%20[%7B%5Cn%22GameOddId%22:%20509945,%5Cn%22Sportsbook%22:%20%22BetDSI%22,%5Cn%22GameId%22:%2053614,%5Cn%22Created%22:%20%222018-09-28T14:12:36%22,%5Cn%22Updated%22:%20%222018-09-28T16:27:12%22,%5Cn%22HomeMoneyLine%22:%20-185,%5Cn%22AwayMoneyLine%22:%20169,%5Cn%22HomePointSpread%22:%20-1.7,%5Cn%22AwayPointSpread%22:%201.7,%5Cn%22HomePointSpreadPayout%22:%20140,%5Cn%22AwayPointSpreadPayout%22:%20-163,%5Cn%22OverUnder%22:%209.0,%5Cn%22OverPayout%22:%20-123,%5Cn%22UnderPayout%22:%20-123%5Cn%7D],%5Cn%22LiveOdds%22:%20[]%5Cn%7D]';%5Cn$array%20=%20(array)json_decode($array);%5Cn//Este%20seria%20si%20tuvieses%20mas%20de%20un%20indice%20dentro%20de%20tu%20json%20array%5Cnforeach($array%20as%20$clave%20=%3E%20$valor)%7B%5Cn%20echo%20'GameId%20=%20'.$valor-%3EGameId.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20echo%20'Season%20=%20'.$valor-%3ESeason.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20echo%20'DateTime%20=%20'.$valor-%3EDateTime.'%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20if(is_array($valor-%3EPregameOdds))%7B%5Cn%20foreach($valor-%3EPregameOdds%20as%20$clave2%20=%3E%20$valor2)%7B%5Cn%20echo%20'GameOddId%20=%20'.$valor2-%3EGameOddId.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20echo%20'Sportsbook%20=%20'.$valor2-%3ESportsbook.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20echo%20'Created%20=%20'.$valor2-%3ECreated.'%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20%7D;%5Cn%20%7D;%5Cn%7D;%5Cn//Este%20seria%20si%20siempre%20accederias%20al%20primer%20indice%20de%20tu%20array%5Cnecho%20'GameId%20=%20'.$array[0]-%3EGameId.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cnecho%20'Season%20=%20'.$array[0]-%3ESeason.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cnecho%20'DateTime%20=%20'.$array[0]-%3EDateTime.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn?%3E)

```
<?php

    $array = '[{
                "GameId": 53614,
                "Season": 2018,
                "SeasonType": 1,
                "Day": "2018-09-28T00:00:00",
                "DateTime": "2018-09-28T14:10:00",
                "Status": "InProgress",
                "AwayTeamId": 16,
                "HomeTeamId": 20,
                "AwayTeamName": "CHW",
                "HomeTeamName": "MIN",
                "GlobalGameId": 10053614,
                "GlobalAwayTeamId": 10000016,
                "GlobalHomeTeamId": 10000020,
                "PregameOdds": [{
                     "GameOddId": 509945,
                     "Sportsbook": "BetDSI",
                     "GameId": 53614,
                     "Created": "2018-09-28T14:12:36",
                     "Updated": "2018-09-28T16:27:12",
                     "HomeMoneyLine": -185,
                     "AwayMoneyLine": 169,
                     "HomePointSpread": -1.7,
                     "AwayPointSpread": 1.7,
                     "HomePointSpreadPayout": 140,
                     "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -163,
                     "OverUnder": 9.0,
                     "OverPayout": -123,
                     "UnderPayout": -123
               }],
               "LiveOdds": []
             }]';

    $array = (array)json_decode($array);

    //Este seria si tuvieses mas de un indice dentro de tu json array
    foreach($array as $clave => $valor){
      echo 'GameId = '.$valor->GameId.'<br>';
      echo 'Season = '.$valor->Season.'<br>';
      echo 'DateTime = '.$valor->DateTime.'<br><br>';

      if(is_array($valor->PregameOdds)){

        foreach($valor->PregameOdds as $clave2 => $valor2){
          echo 'GameOddId = '.$valor2->GameOddId.'<br>';
          echo 'Sportsbook = '.$valor2->Sportsbook.'<br>';
          echo 'Created = '.$valor2->Created.'<br><br>';
        };

      };

    };

    //Este seria si siempre accederias al primer indice de tu array
    echo 'GameId = '.$array[0]->GameId.'<br>';
    echo 'Season = '.$array[0]->Season.'<br>';
    echo 'DateTime = '.$array[0]->DateTime.'<br>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la funcion [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) hace lo contrario al json_encode

Comment: Aunque tu respuesta apunta a una solución, las respuestas que solo contienen un enlace se consideran de baja calidad. Se recomienda que la respuesta contenga la solución/explicación/ejemplo.